# How to setup connection string in C# ASP.NET for SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

```
<connectionString>
  <add name="SchoolContext"
       connectionString="Data Source=(local); database=Sample; integrated security=true;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"      
   />
```

Above is my connection string. But when I run application it gives an error named:

> The configuration section 'connectionString' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

There should be `<connectionStrings>...</connectionStrings>` not `<connectionString>...`

See www.connectionstrings.com for details about various configurations.

Comment: oh!! I didn't noticed at all. Thanks a lot @Giorgi Nakeuri

Answer (score 1):

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

Try this connectionstring style

```
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated 
Security=true;AttachDbFileName=C:\MyFolder\MyData.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```